# Reset a password in android without firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android . I have done login application and storing username , password in sqlite which is inbuilt in android.

I have added validation whether credentials are there in sqlite or not.

Now I want to implement **forgot/reset password** option.

Below are my queries.

1. Is there any other way apart from firebase reset password ?
2. If I use firebase after resetting new password ,how to store the updated password in sqlite(in my table).
3. Do I need to use completely firebase instead of sqlite ?

Comment: Why are you looking to store the password on the device? Since you're using Firebase Authentication, it will automatically restore the user's authentication state when the application is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The point of saving password locally on device I see only if the user want to hide some info on his device. Please correct me if im wrong.

a) if your login password saves local so you dont need firebase to reset it. Just write separate logic to get fields from database and update it

b) as i mentioned above just use regular sqlite insert / update for that

c) if you want to save login/password NOT on device use firebase (it can be firebase auth) if you dont want to save it in cloud use sqlite

Comment: In case if I use sqlite  (local db) , how to trigger reset mail with OTP or link , How to validate user entered OTP is correct or not

Comment: In case you use sqlite your password login saved in sqlite right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar you need to extract value from field password field then get password value for that user from db (firebase or sqlite) compare them and if they are similar so it is correct if not is not

Comment: @PraveenKumar please let me know any questions on that or you could accept as an answer my solution

Comment: I accept your answer